# Generate SSH key with Terraform and always add to ssh-agent

Tags: ssh, terraform

With Terraform I generate an SSH key with the [private key provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/tls/latest/docs/resources/private_key):

```
resource "tls_private_key" "cluster_key_private" {
  algorithm = "ED25519"
}
```

Now to automatically add the key to the ssh-agent keychain I have tried to run a `null_resource`:

```
resource "null_resource" "sshkey_add" {
  triggers = {
    always_run = "${timestamp()}"
  }
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<-EOT
      eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
      echo '${tls_private_key.cluster_key_private.private_key_openssh}' | tr -d '\r' | ssh-add -
    EOT
  }
}
```

Still when I check for added keys:

```
❯ ssh-add -L
The agent has no identities.
```

Comment: You want terraform to modify its surrounding environment?? That does not sound like a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides that you shouldn't do it, I'm pretty sure it's impossible.

ssh-agent is daemon which is run in shell. If you run it from terraform than it's alive as long as terraform process.

It's equivalent of:

```
(eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"; ssh-add ~/.ssh/your-ssh-key)
```

run it on your clean terminal session and you'll see that `your-ssh-key` will not be available. Remember about parenthesis - they run subshell.

Bottom line is - you can't modify parent environment from subprocess.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: what would happen if he'd add the command to e.g. `.bashrc` and source it using null resource?

Comment: @MarkoE what do you mean by "source it using null resource"?

Comment: Using the command `source .bashrc` if that makes any sense at all. :)

Comment: sorry... didn't get it. But no. It would be the same. It would source it inside this `subshell`.